# issue related to PagedResultList while trying to upgrade to grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails

I had a unit test written in groovy 1.3.7 in which I had returned PagedResultList like this

```
return new PagedResultList(myList.list())
```

Now that I have upgraded to 2.2.4 and ran this unit test I am getting an exception

```
|  groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: grails.orm.PagedResultList(java.util.ArrayList)
```

because the constructor is changed.

How should I make it work to return PagedResultList?

Comment: `MyDomain.createCriteria().list()` already returns a `PagedResultList` so you can use it.

Comment: Gives this exception ....  |  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: myList.createCriteria() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: **MyDomain** instead of **myList**. Criteria Builder is got from the Class instance of domain class, it is a dynamic property like `MyDomain.findBy*`.

Comment: oh!.. ya .. typo error ... it's MyDomain only... groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: MyDomain.createCriteria() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: Can you share your test class?

Comment: is there any way I could mock
PagedResultList(GrailsHibernateTemplate template, Criteria crit)